# Datastore: Batch must be in progress to put()

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Datastore API client library to upload an entity with batch on datastore. My version is 1.6.0

This is my code:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()

batch = client.batch()

key = client.key('test', 'key1')
entity = datastore.Entity(
    key,
    exclude_from_indexes=['attribute2'])
entity.update({
    'attribute1': 'hello',
    'attribute2': 'hello again',
    'attribute3': 0.98,
})
batch.put(entity)
```

And I am getting this error when I do batch.put():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 185, in put
    raise ValueError('Batch must be in progress to put()')
ValueError: Batch must be in progress to put()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short answer:*** As stated by @JimMorrison in his answer, you need to call the [`batch.begin()` method](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datastore/batches.html#google.cloud.datastore.batch.Batch.begin) when beginning a batch in Datastore, unless you are using the `with` statement, as explained in [the documentation for `google.cloud.datastore.batch.Batch`](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datastore/batches.html).

---

***Long answer:*** The answer in *short answer* works, however working with batches directly is not the recommended approach according to the documentation. The [Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations) offers some information about how to work with batch operations, differentiating two types of batch operations:

- **Non-transactional batch:** these are some predefined methods (generally having the `_multi` appendix, indicating that it will work over multiple entities simultaneously) that allow to operate on multiple objects in a single Datastore call. These methods are `get_multi()`, `put_multi()` and `delete_multi()`, but they are not executed *transactionally*, i.e. it is possible that only some operations in the request have ended successfully if an error happens.
- **Transactions:** atomic operations which are guaranteed to never be partially applied, i.e. either all operations are applied, or none (if an error occurs). This is a nice feature that comes in handy depending on the time of operations you are trying to perform.

According to the documentation about Datastore's [`Batch` class](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions), the `Batch` class is overridden by the `Transaction` class, so unless you want to perform some specific operations with the underlying `Batch`, you should probably work with transactions instead, as explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions), where you will find more examples and best practices to work with. This practice is preferred to the one you are using, which is working with the `Batch` class directly, which is in fact overridden by `Transaction`.

---

**TL;DR:** `batch.begin()` will solve the issue in your code, as you need to initialize the batch with the [`_IN_PROGRESS` status](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/batch.html#Batch.begin). However, if you want to make your life easier, and make an abstracted usage of batches through transactions, with better documentation and examples, I would recommend the usage of transactions instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explicitly call batch.begin() if you aren't doing the puts in a context, i.e. using the *with* keyword.